# What is the equivalent documentation for datatype transforms for tf2?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For `tf`, there is https://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h.html which provides a bunch of convenience functions for converting between messages and `tf` classes.

What is the equivalent of this for `tf2`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338084/what-is-the-equivalent-documentation-for-datatype-transforms-for-tf2?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a new package [tf2 conversions interface](http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/tf2/html/) with a [tutorial on doing conversions](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Migration/DataConversions)

As well as tutorials on how to implement conversions for your own datatypes: [c++](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Create%20Data%20Conversion%20Package%20%28C%2B%2B%29) and [python](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Create%20Data%20Conversion%20Package%20%28Python%29)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2019-11-22**:
I think the first link "tf2_conversions" is linking to this question

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-11-22**:
sorry I forgot to paste the link. It had no url. Updated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-22**:
@tfoote: the link you added links to `tf_conversions`. Was that intentional?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-11-22**:
Nope that was me trying to fix it too quickly. The updated API is built into tf2, API docs now linked above.